# How to encode URL string without escape ':' and '/' characters using java?

Tags: java, url, encoding

I hope to encode a string to a url, but `URLEncoder.encode()` cannot do it quite well:

```
URLEncoder.encode("http://www.example.com/1/hello world", "utf8")
```

will result in

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F1%2Fhello+world
```

What I hope to get is:

```
http://www.example.com/1/hello+world
```

without encoding the `/` and `:` characters.

---

**EDIT**

This is a just a simple example here, actually I have many non-ascii characters in the url.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert "%3A" to ":" and convert "%2F" to "/" after encode. eg:

```
String ret = URLEncoder.encode("http://www.example.com/1/hello world", "utf8");
String ret2 = ret.replace("%3A", ":").replace("%2F", "/");
```

ret2 is what you want..